# Heroku build failled - React

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Hello when I deploy with Heroku, I got this messages.

I keep fixing it, but still I can't get the solution.

```
----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.22.17
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
       warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
       warning " > styled-components@5.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 30.02s.
       
-----> Build
       Running build (yarn)
       yarn run v1.22.17
       $ react-scripts build
       Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
       Failed to compile.
       
       ./src/App.js
       Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
       
       
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import { GlobalStyle } from './global.style';
import Work from './components/Work';
Import Footer  './Footer';
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route>
            <ScrollToTop />
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/work" component={Work}></Route>
 
         
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

package.josn

```
{
  "name": "design",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node":"14.15.1",
    "npm":"6.14.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.40.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

No idea, why it is not working...

Actually, I deployed with gitpages. but I realized react SPA is not applied on GitPages. So I think about using Heroku.
But I don't know why it not working

Comment: react-router-dom v6 does not export `Switch` anymore, please check: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: @keikai Thank you! I change `Swtich` to `Routes `. However, after that the page is not change... can you give me advise?

Comment: you may need to follow the docs carefully till the very end to finish your upgrade issues.

Comment: 1) You should correct import statement of Footer component. It should be lowercase. 2) Can you place Footer component right above `</Router> ` and try again 3) You are rendering two components inside your first `Route`. IMay be you can render only one component? 4) Maybe the main problem is with `yarn` . Can you recreate your project with `npm`